# How to delete a Javascript object element?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code to update any given property inside a JS object:

```js
var main = {
          items: [
                  {
                    "name": "T-Shirt",
                    "description": "Green XL",
                    "quantity": "1",
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Shoes",
                    "description": "Running, Size 10.5",
                    "quantity": "2",
                  }
                ]
        };

let project = main.items.find((p) => {
    return p.name === 'Shoes';
});

project.quantity = '3';
console.log(main); //shoes quantity is now 3
```

And it works, however, i want it to also be able to delete the whole `project` variable (for example, the whole `Shoes` block). I tried:

```js
let project = main.items.find((p) => {
    return p.name === 'Shoes';
});
delete project;

console.log(main); //shoes still exist
```

But it doesn't work. What would be the best way to delete the property?

Edit: My main issue here was about finding the `index` of the element to be deleted. The chosen answer below provides the solution.

Comment: @Seblor In my research i tried applying the answers listed there but i wasn't able to getthe `index` of the array element i want to delete

Comment: To get the index, you just need to use `findIndex` instead of `find`.

Comment: @Seblor thanks, i didn't knew about `findIndex `.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `delete` operator like this. To remove the found item from the array in-place, you will want to use [`Array#splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
const foundIndex = main.items.findIndex((p) => {
  return p.name === 'Shoes';
});

if (foundIndex !== -1) main.items.splice(foundIndex, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this is exactly what i wanted to do. I was at a loss on how to find the array index of the property i wanted to delete.

Comment: this is not how it suppose to be done, as with this approach you are mutating the object which side effects is an anti pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
main.items = main.items.filter(p => p.name !== 'Shoes');
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight, for some reason, when using this code and then the resulting object is processed by my application, it returns an error, but when i use the code in the accepted solution it works fine.